FPDF in PHP: How to create a link, e. g. on page 1 to a position on page 6?
Currently I'm creating a multipage PDF by use of FPDF in PHP. Works fine so far but there is one issue I cannot resolve:
I need to set links, e. g. on page 1 referencing a position in page 6. Now I'm in trouble: When creating page 1 I need to specify the page and the y position as parameters of SetLink. However, as page 6 is not yet existing, y position is unknown. How to fix this in a sophisticated manner?

Create the link with AddLink(), keep the link identifier handy, create the rest of the document, call SetLink() on the link once the position is known?

That reads promising, testing it will take some time as the complete procedure is a bit complex. Gonna give feedback ASAP.

Alex Howansky
This works like a charm, many thanks! Great that the developers of FPDF had this situation in mind.

Ha ha glad it worked out, that was a wild-ass guess. :)
